# bpftrace execsnoop not catch "echo" command

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I'm trying to figure out what execsnoop can catch or not. \

##### ENV

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
5.15.0-48-generic
bpftrace v0.16.0
```

##### Terminal 1

```
execsnoop.bt
```

##### Terminal 2

```
ls
/usr/bin/echo
/usr/bin/echo a
strace echo a
echo a          # Not showed in Terminal 1
echo            # Not showed in Terminal 1
```

- The docs say it catches which event call exec() *https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/master/tools/execsnoop_example.txt*. But command `strace echo a` actualy call it. *https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/pull/1490/files* \

```
>strace echo a
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "a"], 0x7fff01460c38 /* 30 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55d40d778000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fff0f437c90) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f93860f4000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `strace echo a` forces the use of `/usr/bin/echo`, a binary which your shell `exec()` into, whereas just running plain `echo` in the terminal uses a built-in from your shell, and as such does not trigger an `exec()`.

This is why `/usr/bin/echo a` works as expected as well.

`info echo` from bash mentions the built-in:

```
   Due to shell aliases and built-in ‘echo’ functions, using an
unadorned ‘echo’ interactively or in a script may get you different
functionality than that described here.  Invoke it via ‘env’ (i.e., ‘env
echo ...’) to avoid interference from the shell.
```

You will also likely get different outputs from `echo --help` and `/usr/bin/echo --help`.